# Excel web add-in functions work on Excel 365 desktop, but don't appear on Excel 365 for the Web

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

I created an Excel add-in and I'm hosting it on my server. It has buttons, taskpanes, and functions.

If I add the manifest file to Excel 365 desktop, everything works fine.

If I upload the same manifest file to Excel web, everything works fine, except functions are not showing up inside a spreadsheet.

What I figured so far is that I have to add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to functions.json.

The only place where I can find "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is webpack.config.json for dev.

```
devServer: {
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  },      
  https: (options.https !== undefined) ? options.https : await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions(),
  port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000
}
```

Have any of you had this problem with a web add-in? I can't find anywhere answer to my question. Should I modify the functions.json file or webpack.config.js? How to add it to production?

These are errors, I receive.

[image]

Inside chrome console, I also have this message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://seo.example.com/functions.json' from origin 'https://excel.officeapps.live.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: Really, nobody knows how to show excel custom function in Excel for the web?

Answer (score 0):

It works now. I modified the Nginx configuration in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.

```
http {
...
   add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
...
}
```

Now, the functions are visible and work.